# How to Generate the Kinect Images

Tags: image-processing, filters, computer-vision, machine-learning

[image] What filters are used to get an image like one on the left? I need to find the body pose of a person in a picture.

Comment: First of all, grey scale colours correspond to depth map. Secondly, as far as I know, Kinect is using the Random Forests for body pose estimation after feature extraction.

Comment: Might be helpful: [Key Developments in Human Pose Estimation for Kinect](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/189089/ks_book_2012.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of the Depth Map imaging of the Kinect.
Both the depth mask and the RGB image are used to generate features for a Random Forest estimator to generate the pose estimation.

See [Key Developments in Human Pose Estimation for Kinect](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/189089/ks_book_2012.pdf).

**Remark**: Based on @[jojeck](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/8202/jojeck) comment.